# Changing the default font for StandardForm I/O from 'New Courier' to 'Consolas'?

Tags: fonts, wolfram-mathematica, frontend

I've searched without finding an exact solution for this... Does anyone know how to override  Mathematica's default Monospaced font so all StandardForm Input/Output, including in the help browser, render in 'Consolas'?

The option inspector isn't helping much (probably because I don't know what I'm looking for?). There is also a 'font substitutions' list --- which I find confusing because of what appear to be circular references (i.e., includes things like: Courier -> New Courier and New Courier -> Courier)

Here's a screenshot comparing the two fonts at 125%.

[image]

Comment: IMO, your LCD screen has an inverted subpixel arrangement (BGR) than mine (RGB), which makes the screenshot very ugly... Also, the font is "Courier New"...

Comment: Not sure about the BGR vs RGB...(screen is Sony Z, FHD) I'm guessing it looks crappy because of the MS Snipping tool and/or the fact it's magnified by 125%. Courier New? Noted. :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `Input` and `Output` cell types get their font from the `StandardForm` cell style (in `Core.nb`, inherited by `Default.nb`), so you'd need to make or edit that style cell in the desired stylesheet, for example:

```
Cell[StyleData["StandardForm"],
 FontFamily->"Consolas",
 FontSize->12,
 FontWeight->"Plain",
 FontSlant->"Plain"]
```

Example:

[image: editing a StyleSheet]

You don't have to paste in the `Cell` expression, you can insert the desired type with the dropdown menu or enter the name in the "Enter a style name" box and then style the select the resulting cell and use the **Format** menu to adjust the style to your whims.

Comment: This is cleaner.  Why is StandardForm not in the drop-down list?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I agree why the heck isn't StandardForm in the list?!? Prior to asking, I actually had opened up Core.nb (based on an old post on MathGroup), but I didn't see StandardForm in the drop-down. Further confusing me was the fact that Input shows up as formatted with Times. Thanks to both of you guys for your help!

Comment: `StandardForm` definition is located in "FormatType Styles" subsection of "Styles for Mathematica System-specific Elements" section in the Core.nb. Probably the reason why it is not listed in the drop-down list is that it is located in subsection, not section of Core.nb.

Comment: @Michael or @Mr.Wizard: Do either of you know if this feature is disabled in Mma student version? I've tried to create my own style sheet, but it just doesn't seem to work (it only fixes the current cell I'm in). Also, I can't edit `Default.nb/Core.nb`...

Comment: @R. M. You can't edit Default.nb/Core.nb because they have by default options `Editable->False,
 Saveable->False` inherited from "Notebook" style defined in StylesheetFormatting.nb. If you open Default.nb in a text editor you could see the option `StyleDefinitions->"StylesheetFormatting.nb"` before line `(* End of Notebook Content *)`. For having ability to modify this Notebook you can replace this option with for example `StyleDefinitions -> "PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"` or remove it. I recommend you do not modify the original file but save it as separate copy first.

Comment: What if I want to remove this self-made style definition? Does it exist in the menu forever? (It doesn't though…)

Answer (score 6):

Open the notebook you want to change.

Go to Format > Edit Stylesheet...

Paste this into the bottom of that window (change Verdana to whatever you want):

```
Cell[
    StyleData["Input"], 
    PrivateFontOptions -> {"FontPostScriptName" -> "Verdana"}
]
```

You should get a pop-up asking if you want to "interpret the text."  Click yes.

Save and reload your notebook.

If you want to do this for all notebooks, then you should edit the Default.nb style sheet.

Comment: What is the difference between using `FontFamily->"Verdana"` and `PrivateFontOptions -> {"FontPostScriptName" -> "Verdana"}` this way?

Comment: Use Michael Pilat's method.  This was basically a hack to get around my ignorance of StandardForm being a valid Style Sheet section.